# Can I withdraw questions?

Tags: support, closed-questions

One of my questions [Are most webserver benchmarks useless?](https://serverfault.com/questions/538258/are-most-webserver-benchmarks-useless) has been put on hold as primarily opinion-based. Having re-read the ServerFault guidelines, I have realized that not being a technical problem, this question, while interesting, is not appropriate here.

Can I withdraw the question instead of having it closed or deleted?

Answer (score 6):

Nope.

You may delete your question (the closest thing we have to withdrawing it), or leave it "on hold" (converts to "closed" automatically after 5 days), but honestly your question, while "primarily opinion based", isn't a bad one. It's even got an upvote on it and two decent answers.

I don't see any reason for you to delete it.

Comment: Thanks! Will leave it on then...I suppose closed is better than deleted.

Answer (score 5):

To expand on voretaq7's answer, my understanding is that the algorithms that StackExchange uses to determine whether someone is a "problem user" also take into account what percentage of your questions were deleted. So be sure you think it over before deleting and also that you think questions through carefully and research them before you post.

Comment: Yup - that's part of the point behind this -- you can "withdraw" a question at any time by deleting it, but someone asks and deletes tons of questions (because they have a lot of `herp-derp/well-duh` moments) it generates a lot of noise/churn on the site. It takes a pattern for the system to start imposing sanctions, but that's one of several factors it tracks.